# Apache / Laragon + Composer autoload issue

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, autoload, laragon

I just started an attempt to create a simple Router (I tried several solutions like AltoRouter and as nothing worked, I wanted to started a very simple one).
The Composer autoload can't reach the namespace.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Router' not found in C:\laragon\www\router\index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\router\index.php on line 6

I did the "composer dump-autoload" and the "composer update commands" and even tried an home made autoloader.

Here is the architecture of my project :

- **router**
- > src
- ```
    > Router
  ```
- ```
       Router
  ```
- ```
       Route
  ```
- > vendor
- ```
    autoload
  ```
- .htaccess
- index.php
- composer.json
- composer.lock

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "root/router",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "********",
            "email": "************"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Router;

$router = new Router($_GET[$url]);

$router->get('/home', function(){ echo 'welcome on home page'; });

$router->run();
```

Here is my Router class

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\Route;

class Router {

    public $url;
    private $routes = [];

    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function get($path, $callable)
    {
        $route = new Route($path, $callable);
        $this->routes['GET'][] = $route;
    }

    public function post($path, $callable)
    {
        $route = new Route($path, $callable);
        $this->routes['POST'][] = $route;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo print_r($this->routes);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Here is my Route.php class

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Route {

    public function __construst($path, $callable)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->callable = $callable;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your words, can you share what is unclear about the error message?

Comment: The error message is clear : the script can't find the class Router. My real question is why ? My namespaces look ok. I tried to require class Router but it doesn't work either

Comment: If I require Route.php it seems I get what I wan't but I thought it was the autoload purpose to avoid all those requires in index.php.

Comment: Yes autoload prevents to have to use require. If a PSR-4 autoloader "does  not work" it has problems finding the file to include on disk by the configured autolaoder config. I find your question hard to read where it is about the part of the actual file-system layout you have in use (the bullet points I guess that was for?), e.g. I don't see any file-names. If on disk it is closely chaotic, perhaps the autoloader also has problems to find the file? (your assumptions so far are all correct btw.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the namespace.
Try this:

```
namespace App\Router
```

then type `composer dump-autoload`